# GCD: How to change timer fire interval

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

This may sound a newbie question anyway, I'm very new to GCD

I've following code :

```
int interval = 2;
int leeway = 0;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
if (timer) {
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * interval), interval * NSEC_PER_SEC, leeway);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
        [self someMethod];
    });
    dispatch_resume(timer);
}
```

Where someMethod is :

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Thread 1");
}
```

How do I change the `timer`'s fire interval property in someMethod ?

Comment: A leeway of 0 nanoseconds for a 2 second timer is a little unforgiving :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the answer on my own, calling `dispatch_source_set_timer` with new interval value is enough