# Fetching data for every 2 mins

Tags: objective-c

I need to call a Rest Api every 2 mins to update the data in my View. What is the best solution to do it.

What I've done was used a `NSTimer` to call a web service function in `iOS` asynchronously and update the data in the view. Is there a better solution which I can follow.

Comment: You can also try to perform selector with delay: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with GCD:

```
- (void)updateData{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Fetch data on a background thread:
        NSURL *url = ...;
        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        if (contents) {
            NSMutableArray *array= [NSMutableArray new];

           //..do your stuff here

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update data array and reload your view.
                //if it is table reload it, if it is view refresh it
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And using `dispatch_source_set_timer`, check this [GCD: How to change timer fire interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070026/gcd-how-to-change-timer-fire-interval)